# Can Unity handle perfectly multiple render of differents sizes of the same picture?

Tags: c#, image, performance, unity-game-engine, memory

If I have two pictures slots in my game, one displayed as an icon and one displayed as the full image.

Should I have two differents pictures in my Resources folder or can I use the same picture ?

The question is mostly about performance and memory consumption. Is it better to load one picture and let unity resize it, or load two differents pictures.

Comment: Hmm, this is probably a "it depends" question. Maybe go with Mipmaps? As far as I know, they are normally used for textured rendered at a distance, but maybe you can use them in your use case as well?